# Imported package edition - Ressource null pointer exception

Tags: java

I have imported some sources from a previous work in my actual application, the algorithma is working fine still running itself correctly like it did before, BUT when i tried to change some ressources such as a specific image or a sound using an other file in the variable declaration, the null pointer exception showed up. 
I made sure my new files where correctly placed in the usual ressource file for the old application.
I tried to do something else, for instance i've took a random file from my desktop and renamed it to a file that was used in the old program resource file.
Then i've swaped the two files. (same type of course) 
The same error showed itself, which is quite normal because it's related to the pointer.

Do you have any clue on how to use new ressources on an imported package source, or just how to make it see the new ressource files ?

Here is the message i get :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(StandardMidiFileReader.java:205)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(MidiSystem.java:836)
    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:174)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1145)
    at org.game.Pacman.<init>(Pacman.java:94)
    at org.game.Pacman.run(Pacman.java:80)
    at org.menu.Start.main(Start.java:82)
```

So i solved the issue with image but not with the sound file.
For the image i had to place it in the new ressource folder and not the old one. 
But for the sound when i do that i still get the previous message error due to that line :

```
sample[4]=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("Ressources/Sounds/Dubit.wav"));
```

Comment: Can you share us the code used at org.game.Pacman?

Comment: the FQDN `game.org` currently is a spam site (im guessing you're not the author) - so your package-name is wrong and `Ressources` sounds very fishy, im guessing you actually meant `resources`, which is the standard path and will work out of the box

Comment: see [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) for details on the naming convention

Comment: game.org is just the name i gave to the package, it has nothing to do with any particular site.

Comment: Thanks for the naming convention it will help me a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i just had some issues with the file location. 
I moved my .wav to the new corresponding class file.
Thanks for the participation !

Comment: This not an answer. You should specify what is the *some issues* in you answer